# Pass enum to a generic class in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to create a generic typescript type which takes an enum and then verifies that keys in the type belong to that enum. I am looking for something like this:

```
enum Cars {
  Toyota = 'toyota',
  Lada = 'lada',
}

enum Planes {
  Boeing = 'boeing',
  Airbus = 'airbus',
}

type ImageList<T> = {
  // `key in Planes` works, but `key in T` doesn't
  [key in T]: string;
}

// And that's how I will use the type:
const images: ImageList<Planes> = {
  [Planes.Boeing]: 'https://...jpg',
  [Planes.Airbus]: 'https://...jpg',
};
```

The `[key in T]` syntax is invalid, although `[key in Planes]` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

To do that, I did a union of the enums with the `extends` keyword:

```
type ImageList<T extends Cars | Planes> = {
  [key in T]: string;
}
```

Comment: Also you can `Record`: `type ImageList<T extends Cars | Planes> = Record<T, string>`